# Formatting the response XML of a WebService when using Savon

Tags: ruby, web-services, savon

I'm working using an external Webservice which I consume using the Savon gem.

I **want** to process the response of the WebService, **before Savon**, in order to clean the XML and get the correct Hash to work with. Currently, the Savon call method, answers with the Hash:

```
{:envelope => {
     :body => {
         :get_method_result => {
             :result=>"OK", 
                 :dataset_xml => "
                     <NewDataSet>
                         <xs:schema id=\"NewDataSet\" xmlns=\"\"........
```

Wich, as you can see, after `dataset_xml` has an XML string. So I have to take this and process it in order to have a full Hash.

All of this is happening because my response has thing like: `&lt;NewDataSet&gt;\r\n  &lt;xs:schema id=\"NewDataSet\" xmlns=\` inside it's XML, which if I could be able to fix, then I wouldn't need to do all the after-process to turn it into a Hash.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try to parse the xml your self with nokogiri gem. Have you tried that already?

I would simply try

```
Nokogiri::XML(response[:body])
```

Comment: It obviously works... but it's not what I'm asking :)

Comment: The WS response doesn't have consistent XML, it has <,> symbols and &gt, &lt... so, at the end, after Savon, not everything is a Hash... some values are Strings of XML. This forces me to do thing like the one you're suggesting, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I guess you must clean it first and then parse it. Probably someone already done a gem for that but I couldn't find it. Still, seems a easy thing to do :) Just replace ` &gt` into `<` and then do the nokogiri parsing.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have to clean it and then parse it. But don't want to yet, I suppose it's a very common problem.. so it should have a standard solution within Savon or Nokogiri. I can't be the only one working with WebServices like these...

Comment: Well, I hope it's not that common :p Maybe if you show us a larger part of the response someone can help you better. It's hard to tell what's happening or what can solve your problem with the sample you gave. Show us the raw xml, on the response.

Answer (score 0):

A friend solved it, he added a module named [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html) to Apache. I used it to parse the incoming XML, extracting the CDATA characters. With tha being done, the Savon gem received a clean XML which was parsed perfectly, in one step, to a Hash.

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|CDATAREGEX|' '|i"
</Location>
```